# Azure Copy Alternative in Python SDK - File Share

Tags: azure, azure-devops, storage-file-share

I created a SAS url for a particular fileshare(within a storage account) which allows to copy a directory/file to that file share and not storage account as a whole i.e suppose if I have 2 fileshares(A,B) inside a storage account, this URL will only permit me to read,write,delete,list files/directory inside fileshare(A) if token is for fileshare (A).

```
The url response is https://<storageAccountName>.file.core.windows.net/<fileshareName>?<SAS Token>
```

Now, from above url I am able to perform copy/remove operations(or as per permission specified while generating the above url) using azcopy command line:

```
./azcopy copy "./azcopy_v10.tar.gz" "https://<storageAcccountName>.file.core.windows.net/<fileShareName>?<SAS Token>" --recursive=true
```

Can we do similar thing from fileshare's sdk on azure - programmatically using Python(other languages also fine). ? I saw the reference of file upload at many places, but directory is missing unlike azcopy where we can upload that as well.

```
from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareClient #this doesn't contain upload_directory as a whole(or maybe I have missed :/ )
share_client = ShareClient.from_share_url(r'https://<storageAccountName>.file.core.windows.net/<fileShareName?<SAS>') #establishing connection
#... Now if I can upload folder using share_client it would help
# Example: share_client.folder_upload(folder_to_upload,"location_within_file_share") ?? - imaginary
```

Can someone please help on this ?

Comment: Do you want to upload an entire folder (containing many files) using share client?

Comment: yes, using recursive=true I am able to do that using azcopy, similar stuff I am trying to implement using share client(or alternative imports from sdk)

Comment: Simple answer is no. You will need to do this by iterating over folders, create individual folders and files using the code. This is what azcopy is doing for you.

Comment: Oh, and for that I'll even require to give list access while generating the token right ? Right now I had given just read/write permission, maybe I'll try giving list permission and then iterate and upload file individually then :/

Comment: List access is not required since you're not listing files and folders inside a share. You're listing the local files and folders and for that you don't need this permission.

Comment: Just create and write permissions should be sufficient - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#permissions-for-a-file. HTH.

Comment: yes, actually will try with that by uploading files via iterating. Got it, since we are listing file locally, it won't require over there. Thanks !